# Step to step how to install Cinelerra

Tags: software-installation, cinelerra

I have some problems installing cinelerra on my Ubuntu.

How do I install it?

Comment: The cinelerra-ppa repository is no longer maintained. Go to https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/ to download and install for your system. Note there is no version for Ubuntu 19 yet, so use the Ubuntu 18 install.

Answer (score 11):

If you are asking for [community version](http://cinelerra.org/) of Cinelerra, [there is a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cinelerra-ppa/+archive/ppa) as @Brett Howard said. It worked on my current system. Just used these:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
```

The updating process after installing the PPA is automatic:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: What's the difference between the community version of cinelerra and the standard version? Is there a difference?

Comment: You can read this for an explanation of CE: http://cinelerra.org/docs/cinelerra_cv_manual_en.html#SEC3

Comment: The cinelerra-ppa repository is no longer maintained. Go to https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/ to download and install for your system. Note there is no version for Ubuntu 19 yet, so use the Ubuntu 18 install.

Answer (score 5):

I am the maintainer of the Cinelerra ppa. After some compilation issues, cinelerra is finally available for oneiric (and precise):

https://launchpad.net/~cinelerra-ppa/+archive/ppa

Comment: The cinelerra-ppa repository is no longer maintained. Go to https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/ to download and install for your system. Note there is no version for Ubuntu 19 yet, so use the Ubuntu 18 install.

Answer (score 1):

go to cinellera's official website  cinellera.org and click the arrow at the side of the "download" button on the top and select "cinellera"

u will see 2 options for ubuntu 64bit and 32 bit choose according to your system and download the two links..

you will see those links in your download files in your file manager.....

select them

Comment: The cinelerra-ppa repository is no longer maintained. Go to https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/ to download and install for your system. Note there is no version for Ubuntu 19 yet, so use the Ubuntu 18 install.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your Pc is 32 bit , so i think you must use

```
wget http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra-data_4.4-dmo1_all.deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra_4.4-dmo1_i386.deb
```

but if cannot work as well , maybe you can also get the package from

```
wget http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra-data_4.4-dmo1_all.deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra_4.4-dmo1_amd64.deb
```

and last step is `sudo dpkg -i cinelerra_4.4-*.deb`
and than to run that app you can write the `cinelerra` on terminal

Comment: The cinelerra-ppa repository is no longer maintained. Go to https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/ to download and install for your system. Note there is no version for Ubuntu 19 yet, so use the Ubuntu 18 install.

Answer (score 1):

As of this date, the cinelerra-ppa is no longer maintained. Trying to install using the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa` will give the error:

```
************************************************************************
THIS PPA IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED.
WE RECOMMEND USERS TO TRANSITION TO CINELERRA-GG:
Details and installation: https://cinelerra-gg.org
************************************************************************
```

**So....**

You have to go to https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/ to find both the download you need, and installation instructions.

At this time, there is no Ubuntu 19+ version, so you have to install Ubuntu 18 version.

Also there are plenty of dependencies, and some may be unavailable for your system. The `README` files are your friends.

Answer (score -1):

**To install Cinelerra Community Version:**

Hit Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal window, copy and paste below command to add the ppa repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Latest Cinelerra-CV:

```
sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
```

The ppa support Ubuntu 8.04, 10.04, 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04. Also works on Linux Mint 15, 14, 13.

**To install Cinelerra 4.4 (HV version):**

Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal, copy and paste below command to download the Debs.

For 32-bit:

```
wget http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra-data_4.4-dmo1_all.deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra_4.4-dmo1_i386.deb
```

For 64-bit:

```
wget http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra-data_4.4-dmo1_all.deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra_4.4-dmo1_amd64.deb
```

Then install them (both 32-bit & 64bit):

```
sudo dpkg -i cinelerra_4.4-*.deb
```

For first time launching cinelerra by typing command in terminal, then lock to Unity Launcher.

cinelerra

Comment: The cinelerra-ppa repository is no longer maintained. Go to https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/ to download and install for your system. Note there is no version for Ubuntu 19 yet, so use the Ubuntu 18 install.